# curved lines with css on divs and inputs

Tags: css

Is it possible to create something like this only with css?

[image]

I think with this is this possible but is it also possible with input fields?

Comment: you need to share code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can make something similar using `border-radius` property

**Snippet**

```css
.container{
  border-radius:5%/100px 100px 100px 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<input class="container" />
```

Working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbq5k0Lu/2/)** here. Change the `border-radius` percentage and check the UI change

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with just css, but if you create an svg image with the lateral curved lines than you can do something like:

```
input {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
input::before {
  background: url("curve-sx.svg")
}
input::after {
  background: url("curve-dx.svg")
}
```